# Working with data from multiple database tables

Tags: mysql, vuejs3

I am pullling data from two tables in MYSQL. One table has basic info for items I am tracking. Right now it has two items. So, it has itemid, itemname, aboutitem.

The second table has components for each item in the first table. SO, it has componentID, itemid, componentname, componentinstalldate.

So each item from table one has multiple associated components from table two.

So I want to pull the data and then loop over the data in VUE3 and put all the data for each item from table one. So there should be two sections of data that gets displayed.

I cannot see how to do the loop in vue.
Do I need to change the database tables?

Right now I use an inner join to get the data from two tables.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM bikes
INNER JOIN maintenance
ON bikes.bid = maintenance.bid
```

Here are the table creates.

I have not written the VUE code yet because of the output of the query is not condusive...as I see it...but I am just learning.
Ultimately the vue code would show each bike with all associated components from the maintenance table. As it is now, it lists each bike 8 times...once for each component.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `bikes` (
  `bid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `purchasedate` date NOT NULL,
  `modelyear` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `model` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `about` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

CREATE TABLE `maintenance` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'component ID',
  `bid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'bike ID',
  `component` varchar(25) NOT NULL COMMENT 'name of component',
  `description` text COMMENT 'description of component',
  `installdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mileage` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`)
```

Comment: The published query doesn't seem to have anything in common with the table descriptions. Pleas publish create table statements for both as text (output from show create table<tablename.) And you should publish your vuejs code.